# How do i select only one data and show?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Core;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class container
    {
        public string _Id { get; set; }
        public string Node { get; set; }
        public int SignalSTR { get; set; }
        public float Battery { get; set; }
        public float CEL { get; set; }
        public float WT { get; set; }
        public string OnlineSTAT { get; set; }
        public string FirmVER { get; set; }
        public Int64 Timestamp { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            CallMain(args).Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static async Task CallMain(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            //var server = client.GetServer();
            var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
            //var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("container");
            var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
            var filt = builder.Eq("Node", "001_Iron_Nail") & builder.Eq("WT", "4.3");



            /* Method 1
            using (var cursor = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(doc);
                    }
                }
            } */

            // Method 2
            //var list = await collection.Find(filt).ToListAsync();

            var list = await collection.Find(filt).ToListAsync();
            foreach (var dox in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dox);
            }

            // Method 3
            // await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(X => Console.WriteLine(X));

        } 
    }
}
```

The codes above i am able to filter some conditions to display all the data inside the collection named 'container' in my 'test' database. Would like to ask how should i do about to just print out some of the selected valiue. Like example. I just want battery :

```
Battery 3.5
Battery 3.6
Battery 3.7
```

Comment: try like this: `collection.Find(filt).Select(x=> new { Battery = x.Battery })`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = await collection.Find(filt).ToListAsync();
for (int ii=0; ii<list.Count; ii++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Battery " + list[ii].Battery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can output like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", dox["Node"].ToString(), dox["WT"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a list with only batteries:

```
collection.Find(filt).Project(x => new {x.Battery}).ToList();
```

Alternative you could get all the data from mongo and filter it on client:

```
collection.Find(filt).ToEnumerable().Select(x => x.Battery);
```